# Ubuntu 20.10 crashes on boot when installing virtualbox-guest-x11

Tags: virtualbox, xorg, fullscreen, 20.10, guest-additions

I've installed Ubuntu Server 20.10 on VirtualBox 6.1.16 (Windows 10 Insider Preview host).

I want full screen, so I installed the package `virtualbox-guest-x11`. When I reboot, Ubuntu crashes on boot, and shows the "Oh no! Something went wrong" screen.

I tried installing `virtualbox-guest-x11` on Ubuntu Server 18.04, and everything works fine, it appears to be a problem with 20.10.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.